# What is $k$ in Newtons Law of Cooling?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I am writing the definition of quantities for [Newton's Law of Cooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer) and am not sure what to actually call k$,$ or its units. This is what I have so far

$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_s)$$

Where $\frac{dT}{dt}$ is the rate of cooling measured in degrees Celsius per second $\left[°C\cdot{}s^{-1}\right]$

$T$ is the temperature of the object measured in degrees Celsius $\left[°C\right]$

$T_s$ is the ambient temperature of the objects surrounding measured in degrees Celsius $\left[°C\right]$

$k$ is a constant and has no units? I don't think that's a good enough description

Comment: $T_s$ would have the units $°C$, not $°C·s^{-1}$.

Comment: $k$ in thermodynamics (and quantum mechanics, and some other disciplines touched by either) is [Boltzmann's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_constant). However, in this case, it's a confusingly-named placeholder for a characteristic of the system that may or may not be calculated further on.

Comment: Sorry copy and paste error. So it would be correct to name the k in $P=-kA\frac{dT}{dx}$ as the Boltzmann's constant as well? I have it listed as the thermal conductivity coefficient at the moment

Comment: @user88720 No, it's not Boltzmann's constant. Nor does it correspond to other variables named $k$ in thermodynamics.

Comment: I'm confused. When I look at the Wikipedia pages, it states that both thermal conductivity and the Boltzmann constant are denoted with k...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ in thermodynamics (and quantum mechanics, and some other disciplines touched by either) is [Boltzmann's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_constant).

[Thermal conductivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%27s_law#Fourier.27s_law) (units $\frac{\mathrm W}{\mathrm m^2 \cdot \mathrm K}$) is also named $k$, but that's not what you have there either. Refer to that article for help in deriving what your incomplete equation calls $k$.

Comment: So the k in this is simply an unknown constant and I could simply use x instead?

Comment: @user88720 Well, the name $x$ tends to emphasize that a variable is supposed to be isolated and calculated. Maybe $c_0$ is a good neutral name. But yeah, such use of $k$ is too confusing.

Answer (score 2):

An another form of Newton's law of cooling is:

[image]

(Source:B.L.Worsnop and H.T.Flint, Advanced 
Practical Physics for Students Ninth Edition, 
Macmillan)
So,k in newtons law of cooling is equal to

[image]

where K(in upper case)=thermal conductivity of material
      A=Surface Area exposed,
      m=mass,
      s=specific heat of substance,
      d=thickness of the body.
So.k depends on the nature of the material used and the dimensions of the body.